# zfs-auto-snapshot settings are ignored

Tags: backup, zfs, snapshot

I am not sure what I did wrong that my settings are getting ignored.
I installed the package with everything else and created my pool and datasets:

```
sudo apt-get install zfsutils-linux zfs-auto-snapshot -y
```

Then I adjusted the config:

```
sudo nano /etc/cron.d/zfs-auto-snapshot
```

Content:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

# daily at 2 am and keep 14 snapshots of the daily ones
00 2 * * * root zfs-auto-snapshot -q -g --label=daily --keep=14 //
00 2 * * 0 root zfs-auto-snapshot -q -g --label=weekly --keep=4 //
00 2 1 * * root zfs-auto-snapshot -q -g --label=monthly --keep=18 //
```

But I took a look at the snapshots and I still see hourly snapshots. For example, the timestamp of the daily snapshots is 05:35 like `icybox/appdata/website@zfs-auto-snap_daily-2022-10-15-0535`

What is wrong? The documentation isn't really good. I only guess or even know that the command `zfs set com.sun:auto-snapshot:hourly=false icybox` should deactivate the hourly snaps for this pool but I thought the configuration would even disable it for all of them.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 22.04 LTS @David